# Simulate send and receive using pthreads

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads

I am trying to simulate send and receive functionality using pthreads. I did implement the following code. But some times it hangs or produce wrong results.

```
int g_sender,g_receiver; //global variables to keep track of the sender and receiver
void send(double ** data,int sender,int receiver, int size[],int block_size){
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
    for (i=0;i<size[0];i++)
            memcpy(sharedA[i],data[i],size[1]*block_size);
    g_sender = sender;
    g_receiver = receiver;
    sem_wait(&sem);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

}

void receive(double ** data, int sender,int receiver, int size[],int block_size){
        int i;
    while(!(sender==g_sender && receiver==g_receiver));
    for(i=0;i<size[0];i++)
        memcpy(data[i],sharedA[i],size[1]*block_size);
    g_sender =-1;
    g_receiver = -1;
    sem_post(&sem);
}
```

what do you think I did miss here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a lot :)

- what is the purpose of holding the lock?
- never wait for a semaphore when holding a lock
- always check the return value of library functions. In particular the
  `sem_` functions are interruptible, you **must** check if an
  interrupt happened for `sem_wait`
- if you are not so experienced with POSIX threads just don't use
  `sem_t`. Use mutexes and condition variables instead. They are higher
  level interfaces better suited for application code.

Comment: I am using a lock to protect the global variables sharedA, g_sender, g_receiver from other threads until reading it from the receiver. I use semaphores to simulate blocking send.

Comment: @user504453, in any case alltogether your design doesn't make much sense to me